# Laravel 4 - Datatables - Call to a member function getQuery() on array

Tags: php, laravel, datatable

The following query MySQL works correctly in MySQL MyAdmin.

```
SELECT contacts.id, contacts.gsm, contacts.name, contacts.last_name, contacts.email, contacts.created_at,  if(temp.Count >= 1,temp.Count,0) as newCount
        FROM contacts
        LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT contacts.id, COUNT(groupcontact.id) AS Count
        FROM contacts
        LEFT JOIN groupcontact ON groupcontact.contacts_id = contacts.id
        LEFT JOIN groups ON groups.id = groupcontact.groups_id
        WHERE groups.id = :idGrupo
        GROUP BY contacts.id)
        temp ON temp.id = contacts.id
```

BUT when i try to run with LARAVEL + Datatables in RAW DB, returns this error-
{"error":{"type":"Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException","message":"Call to a member function getQuery() on array","file":"C:\xampp\htdocs\mcdigital\laravel\vendor\bllim\datatables\src\Bllim\Datatables\Datatables.php","line":256}}

I dont know why

---

LARAVEL controller

```
$sql="SELECT contacts.id, contacts.gsm, contacts.name, contacts.last_name, contacts.email, contacts.created_at,  if(temp.Count >= 1,temp.Count,0) as newCount
            FROM contacts
            LEFT JOIN
            (SELECT contacts.id, COUNT(groupcontact.id) AS Count
            FROM contacts
            LEFT JOIN groupcontact ON groupcontact.contacts_id = contacts.id
            LEFT JOIN groups ON groups.id = groupcontact.groups_id
            WHERE groups.id = :idGrupo
            GROUP BY contacts.id)
            temp ON temp.id = contacts.id";
    $usuarios = DB::select( DB::raw($sql), array('idGrupo' => $idGrupo));

    return Datatables::of($usuarios)
    ->add_column('options', '
                    <label class="toggle yesNoGroup pull-left">
                      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-toggle" id="yesNoGroupchk-{{ $id }}" @if(newCount >0)checked@endif>
                      <i></i></label>
                    ')->make();
```

JS Datatables

```
if ($(tablaName).length && !isNaN(idGroup)) {
        var $oTable = $(tablaName).dataTable({
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": '/contact-list-group-load/'+idGroup,
            "autoWidth": true,
            "oLanguage": {
                "sProcessing":     '<image src="/images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Cargando...">',
                "sLengthMenu":     "Mostrar _MENU_ contactos",
                "sSearch":         "Buscar:",
                "sZeroRecords":    "No se encontraron resultados",
                "sInfo":           "Mostrando _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ contactos",
                "oPaginate": {
                    "sFirst":    "Primero",
                    "sLast":     "Último",
                    "sNext":     "Siguiente",
                    "sPrevious": "Anterior"
                }
            },
            "aaSorting": [[0, 'desc']],
            "sDom":
                    "<'row'<'col-xs-6'l><'col-xs-6'f>r>"+
                    "t"+
                    "<'row'<'col-xs-12 text-center tableCuantosRegistros'i><'col-xs-12 text-center'p>>",
            "sLoadingRecords": '<image src="/images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Cargando...">',
            "aoColumnDefs": [
                { "bSearchable": false, "aTargets": [ 5, 6 ] },
                { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 5, 6 ] }
              ],
            "fnDrawCallback": function (oSettings) {

           },
            "iDisplayLength": 100
     });
```

Maybe, just to ask how to convert this mysql query to Laravel Eloquent or Laravel Query Builder. Please advise.

THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: How has this occured, what are you doing? If you look further down the error stack you might find some of your own code that has an error. More details would be good.

Comment: You should provide more information so people here can help you please refer to [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks, i added more code information

Comment: what's your php version? one reason could be php old version sometimes it happens where you get error like "Call to a member function getQuery()" specialy with debian 5.4. does everything else works fine? hope upgrade php version helps.

Comment: Hi! im working (localhost) with Xampp and PHP Version 5.6.3. tHANKS!

Comment: Any success already with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error says all.

You should convert $usuarios **array to Collection** as:

```
$usuarios = DB::select( DB::raw($sql), array('idGrupo' => $idGrupo));
    $usuarios= collect($usuarios);
```

GO AHEAD...
[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35520046/call-to-a-member-function-getquery-on-array/)